# Using kwargs to add key and value in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, keyword-argument

I'm discovering kwargs and want to use them to add keys and values in a dictionary.
I tried this code :

```
def generateData(elementKey:str, element:dict, **kwargs):
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        element[elementKey] = {
           "%s": "%s" %(key,value)
        }
    return element
```

However, when I use it, I have a TypeError :

`*not all arguments converted during string formatting`

I tried with

`element = generateData('city', element, name = 'Paris', label = 'Paris', postcode = '75000')`

and I wanted as result:

`element = {'city': {'name': 'Paris', 'label': 'Paris', 'postcode': '75000'}}`

Would you know where is my error ?

Comment: The reason for the error is that the formatting directive only applies to the string that is to its left - i.e., "%s". However, the solution is offered correctly by Dani Mesejo below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do, since `kwargs` is already a dictionary:

```
def generate_data(elementKey: str, element: dict, **kwargs):
    element[elementKey] = kwargs
    return element


element = {}
element = generate_data('city', element, name='Paris', label='Paris', postcode='75000')
print(element)
```

**Output**

```
{'city': {'name': 'Paris', 'label': 'Paris', 'postcode': '75000'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

```
def generate_data(elementKey: str, **kwargs):
    y = dict()
    y[elementKey] = kwargs
    return y


kwargs = {'name' : 'Paris'  , 'label' : 'Paris', 'postcode':'75000'}
element = generate_data('city', **kwargs )
print(element)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).